# How to install apache superset in linux (linux version 22) machine

Tags: python, apache-superset

IM trying to install apache superset on my linux machine

1. python version 3.8
2. Linux version 22

Im followed this link (https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-from-scratch/)
I have already created the venv using
python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate

After installing apache-superset usig this command (pip install apache-superset) i got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/ubuntu/DHT/superset/superset/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 583, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)   File "/home/ubuntu/DHT/superset/superset/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 900, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))   File "/home/ubuntu/DHT/superset/superset/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 791, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req) pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (cachelib 0.4.1 (/home/ubuntu/DHT/superset/superset/lib/python3.8/site-packages), Requirement.parse('cachelib>=0.9.0'), {'flask-caching'})

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ubuntu/DHT/superset/superset/bin/superset", line 6, in <module>
        from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
      File "/home/ubuntu/DHT/superset/superset/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3252, in <module>
        def _initialize_master_working_set():
      File "/home/ubuntu/DHT/superset/superset/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3235, in _call_aside
        f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ubuntu/DHT/superset/superset/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3264, in _initialize_master_working_set
        working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
      File "/home/ubuntu/DHT/superset/superset/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 585, in _build_master
        return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
      File "/home/ubuntu/DHT/superset/superset/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 598, in _build_from_requirements
        dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
      File "/home/ubuntu/DHT/superset/superset/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 791, in resolve
        raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
    pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (cachelib 0.4.1 (/home/ubuntu/DHT/superset/superset/lib/python3.8/site-packages), Requirement.parse('cachelib>=0.9.0'), {'flask-caching'})
```

AFter pip freeze i got this list

```
aiohttp==3.8.1
aiosignal==1.2.0
alembic==1.8.1
amqp==5.1.1
apache-superset==2.0.0
apispec==3.3.2
async-generator==1.10
async-timeout==4.0.2
attrs==21.4.0
Babel==2.10.3
backoff==2.1.2
billiard==3.6.4.0
bleach==3.3.1
Brotli==1.0.9
cachelib==0.4.1
celery==5.2.7
certifi==2022.6.15
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==2.1.0
click==8.1.3
click-didyoumean==0.3.0
click-plugins==1.1.1
click-repl==0.2.0
colorama==0.4.5
convertdate==2.4.0
cron-descriptor==1.2.31
croniter==1.3.5
cryptography==37.0.4
Deprecated==1.2.13
deprecation==2.1.0
dnspython==2.2.1
email-validator==1.2.1
Flask==2.1.3
Flask-AppBuilder==4.1.3
Flask-Babel==2.0.0
Flask-Caching==2.0.0
Flask-Compress==1.12
Flask-JWT-Extended==4.4.2
Flask-Login==0.6.1
Flask-Migrate==3.1.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
flask-talisman==1.0.0
Flask-WTF==1.0.1
frozenlist==1.3.0
func-timeout==4.3.5
geographiclib==1.52
geopy==2.2.0
graphlib-backport==1.0.3
gunicorn==20.1.0
h11==0.13.0
hashids==1.3.1
holidays==0.10.3
humanize==4.2.3
idna==3.3
importlib-metadata==4.12.0
importlib-resources==5.8.0
isodate==0.6.1
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
jsonschema==4.7.2
kombu==5.2.4
korean-lunar-calendar==0.2.1
Mako==1.2.1
Markdown==3.4.1
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
marshmallow==3.17.0
marshmallow-enum==1.5.1
marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.26.1
msgpack==1.0.4
multidict==6.0.2
numpy==1.22.1
outcome==1.2.0
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.3.5
parsedatetime==2.6
pgsanity==0.2.9
polyline==1.4.0
prison==0.2.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.30
pyarrow==5.0.0
pycparser==2.21
PyJWT==2.4.0
PyMeeus==0.5.11
pyOpenSSL==22.0.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
pyrsistent==0.18.1
PySocks==1.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==0.20.0
python-geohash==0.8.5
pytz==2022.1
PyYAML==6.0
redis==4.3.4
selenium==4.3.0
simplejson==3.17.6
six==1.16.0
slackclient==2.5.0
sniffio==1.2.0
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.24
SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.37.9
sqlparse==0.3.0
tabulate==0.8.9
trio==0.21.0
trio-websocket==0.9.2
typing-extensions==3.10.0.2
urllib3==1.26.10
vine==5.0.0
wcwidth==0.2.5
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==2.1.2
wrapt==1.14.1
wsproto==1.1.0
WTForms==2.3.3
WTForms-JSON==0.3.5
yarl==1.7.2
zipp==3.8.1
```

How to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are running `cachelib version 0.4.1` yet the superset version requires `cachelib version 0.9.0` or higher.
Run the command below to install the required version.

```
pip install cachelib
```